# What Is the body or name of the energy loss off power lines?

Tags: electromagnetism

Every so many feet depending on the frequency there are points of loss of the electrical charges and depending on the surrounding conditions it can vary in omitted losses. I cannot find a photo of this in action ...

Comment: I can't find any like the 1 i took, that is my profile picture. .

Comment: how come i cant find any pictuers of this like the 1 i took thats my profile pic

Answer (score 1):

The three mechanisms of energy loss are Joule Heating, Skin Effect (AC only) and Corona Discharge.

Comment: how come i cant find any pictuers of this like the 1 i took thats my profile pic?

Comment: @Rummyjer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brush_discharge ?

Comment: https://youtu.be/YkSF2muvxxA

Answer (score 0):

You mean resistance? Loss increases with current squared so it needs higher voltage to lose less under constant power. If temperature rises, metal atoms' effective collision area increases and so does resistance.

Or skin effect caused by currents own magnetic field and shape of cable?

Or corona discharge at joints?

Or theft?

Comment: Don't forget radiative losses from the fact that power lines are just really big antennae.

Comment: how come i cant find any pictuers of this

Comment: Like mine taken with my phone..   https://youtu.be/YkSF2muvxxA

Answer (score 0):

It is called a discharge, possibly a  [corona discharge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona_discharge)

> In electricity, a corona discharge is an electrical discharge brought on by the ionization of a fluid surrounding a conductor that is electrically charged. Spontaneous corona discharges occur naturally in high-voltage systems unless care is taken to limit the electric field strength. *The corona will occur when the strength (potential gradient) of the electric field around a conductor is high enough to form a conductive region, but not high enough to cause electrical breakdown or arcing to nearby objects.* It is often seen as a bluish (or other color) glow in the air adjacent to pointed metal conductors carrying high voltages, and emits light by the same property as a gas discharge lamp.

See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t92fxI21M2E)   and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rLrP9mck7eM)  and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tguh8I37HrM).  The last explains it too.

The frequency dependence you mention must depend on the type of extrusions on the lines that could act as a "point". It seems to be a problem in eastern European power lines as the search brings pages with russian alphabet :).

Comment: how come i cant find any pictures of this

Comment: I have given three video links, videos are pictures in series.There is a picture in the wiki link I gave of corona discharge from specific points. How did you make that picture? it looks like a special type of film or timing

Comment: I got more of them..here's how https://youtu.be/YkSF2muvxxA

Comment: you do not explain the lighting . And it is Corona, not "Corna"

Comment: Lighting ?? And it's a certain way to take the pictures of corona loss.. I'm not going to disclose that here

Answer (score 0):

The energy loss is heat energy leaving the lines and possible if you live near really high power lines you may see a glow at night from light energy.
This is just energy conversion.

Comment: how come i cant find any pictutes of this like the 1 i took thats my profile pic.. cant find 1 like my profile pic

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brush_discharge ?

Comment: Here look at my pic. https://youtu.be/YkSF2muvxxA